# AdMob banner custom position different devices unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, admob, offset, banner

In my unity project, I want to create a banner ad that lies on the center bottom with a defined offset in y position. This is because I have some control elements lying on the very bottom of the screen and the banner is supposed to be above them.

With the following command I managed to do that on my testing device (1920 x 1080):

```
bannerView = new BannerView (bannerAdUnitId, AdSize.Banner, 20, 525);
```

However when I switch to my tablet (1280 x 1024) the banner ad appears in the middle left of the screen, far away from where it should be.

Now I wonder what reference google uses for the custom ad position.

With a resolution of 1920x1080 the screen in the google ad positioning reference is 360 units wide and something about 600 high.